# Javascript/jquery: get value from a combined key value array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, key

I am so ashamed of asking such a basic thing but I have been trying to work it out for a long time now and I cannot figure it out :(

I have two arrays. One contains keys and the other values.

I have combined them so I can have one array with the key value pair:

```
var combinedArray = [];
var keysArray = [];
var valuesArray = [];
keysArray = ["LND", "NY", "MAD"];
valuesArray = ["London", "New York", "Madrid"];
var keysArrayLength = keysArray.length;

for (var i = 0; i < keysArrayLength; i++) 
{  
 combinedArray.push({
 key: keysArray[i],
 value: valuesArray[i]
 });  
}
```

Now I need to get the value of a certain key.

For example, I want to have in a variable the value of key "LND"

So I do:

```
var result = $.grep(combinedArray, function(e){ return e.key == 'LND'; });
```

But in result, I get a [Object, Object] instead of London

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.grep` will return to you an array, which consists of objects (which has `key` and `value` fields). So to get value you can use:

```
var result = $.grep(combinedArray, function(e){ return e.key == 'LND'; });
alert(result[0].value);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wv5znq58/).

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation

> The $.grep() method removes items from an array as necessary so that
>   all remaining items pass a provided test

meaning that the result is an array containing the object that matches your filter (is this case the key)

So you'll get it as you normally do from an array `result[0].value`

```js
var combinedArray = [];
var keysArray = [];
var valuesArray = [];
keysArray = ["LND", "NY", "MAD"];
valuesArray = ["London", "New York", "Madrid"];
var keysArrayLength = keysArray.length;

for (var i = 0; i < keysArrayLength; i++){  
   combinedArray.push({
      key: keysArray[i],
      value: valuesArray[i]
   });  
}

var result = $.grep(combinedArray, function(e){ return e.key === 'LND'; });

document.write(result[0].value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

.grep creates array you must use this kind of code

```
var combinedArray = [];
var keysArray = [];
var valuesArray = [];
keysArray = ["LND", "NY", "MAD"];
valuesArray = ["London", "New York", "Madrid"];
var keysArrayLength = keysArray.length;

for (var i = 0; i < keysArrayLength; i++) 
{  
 combinedArray.push({
 key: keysArray[i],
 value: valuesArray[i]
 });  
}

var result = $.grep(combinedArray, function(e){ return e.key == 'LND'; });

console.log(combinedArray);
alert(result[0].value);
```

Example   http://jsfiddle.net/6hza5m5e/1/